# Python - formatting arrays to BED file

Tags: python, format

I am somewhat new to python and hoping for some help formatting a file. I am currently working with a file that looks as follows:

```
    3 5
    3 6
    3 7
    3 8
    3 12
    3 13 
    3 14
    5 1
    5 2
    5 3
```

where the first column represents a row number and the second column represents a column number in a matrix. I'm looking to reformat this file so it looks like:

```
    3 5 8
    3 12 14
    5 1 3
```

How can I do this? The files I want to run this on are much larger than 10 lines this is just an example I've been working with to test my code.

Answer (score 0):

This was supposed to be a `python question` but it looks like an `algorithm problem`. Next time bring to us your algorithm and we can help you write it for python.

---

This algorithm may not be the best solution for your problem, but it will show you what python can do:

```
long_text = '''3 5
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 12
3 13
3 14
5 1
5 2
5 3'''

lines = long_text.split('\n')

last_row = -1
last_column = -1
add_one = True

formatted_text = ''

for line in lines:
    row, column = line.split(' ')
    row = row
    column = column
    if row == last_row:
        if int(column) == int(last_column) + 1:
            if add_one:
                formatted_text = '{} {}'.format(formatted_text, column)
                add_one = False
            else:
                formatted_text = formatted_text[:-(len(last_column)+1)]
                formatted_text = '{} {}'.format(formatted_text, column)
        else:
            formatted_text = '{}\n{} {}'.format(formatted_text, row,
            column)
            add_one = True
    else:
        formatted_text = '{}\n{} {}'.format(formatted_text, row, column)
        add_one = True
    last_row = row
    last_column = column

print (formatted_text)
```

Here follows the SAME algorithm, using list instead:

```
long_text = '''3 5
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 12
3 13
3 14
5 1
5 2
5 3'''

lines = long_text.split('\n')

last_row = -1
last_column = -1
add_one = True

formatted_list = []

for line in lines:
    row, column = line.split(' ')
    row = int(row)
    column = int(column)
    if row == last_row:
        if column == last_column + 1:
            if add_one:
                formatted_list.append(column)
                add_one = False
            else:
                formatted_list.pop(-1)
                formatted_list.append(column)
        else:
            formatted_list.append('\n')
            formatted_list.append(row)
            formatted_list.append(column)
            add_one = True
    else:
        formatted_list.append('\n')
        formatted_list.append(row)
        formatted_list.append(column)
        add_one = True
    last_row = row
    last_column = column

formatted_text = ''
for element in formatted_list:
    formatted_text = '{} {}'.format(formatted_text, element)

print (formatted_text)
```

The `add_one` is used to check if it has to remove the last column, so the code outputs `3 5 8` instead of `3 5 6 7 8`.

Comment: ^that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Sorry about posting in the wrong place.